# Unity Animation: Can I Skip/Forward the played animation by touch?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

Halo guys, I'm literally new to C# on Unity. Can I ask some scripts if I may to you all. The case is somethings like this:  I have an animation that played some sprites on a scene. I want to know if I can skip / forward the animation by touch using C# scripts placed on Empty Game Object. So the animation can move forward for 1 second / 2 seconds if the user touch the screen, so the animation more faster done playing or the user doesn't need to wait the animation that played to be finish.

I just think I may build that function with `for` statement and placed on `void update`. Please correct me if I'm wrong, and if I may put some code on you'r thought. Many thanks and cheers :).